# power spectrum -PSD

Tags: power-spectral-density

I was wandering if someone can help me to understand if there is difference between power spectrum and power spectral density.
Looking here I found that there are differences
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-power-spectrum-and-power-spectral-density

Wikipedia says that are different name for the same thing
"More commonly used is the power spectral density (or simply power spectrum)"
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PSD** (*power spectral density*) : distribution of power (of a WSS random process) along frequency... *Power Spectrum* is the same thing.

For zero mean discrete-time processes, PSD is defined as the DTFT of the ACS:

$$ \boxed{ S_x(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} r_{x}[k] e^{-j \omega m} }$$

Where $r_{x}[m]$ is the ACS (auto-correlation sequence) of the WSS random process $x[n]$. Various authors (or textbooks) prefer different symbols or names for ACS and PSD such as: $\phi_x[m]$ for ACS, or $\Phi_x(\omega)$ for PSD.

Sometimes, the Z-transform approach is used and PSD is defined as

$$ \boxed{ P_x(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} r_{x}[n] z^{-n} }$$

where the spectrum is obtained in the case when $z = e^{j\omega}$.

Comment: Thank you. wikipedia was right :)!!